# Make height change from bottom to top

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a red div which increases height from top to bottom on key down and decreases on key up
I want the height to change from bottom to top instead of top to bottom.
style:

> .load {
> width: 550px;
> height: 0;
> background-color: red;
> position: absolute;
> top: 50px;
> z-index: -1;
> transform: rotate(180deg);
> }
> html:
> `<div class="load"></div>`
> jquery:
> `$(document).ready(function() {
> var animating = false;
> var isExpanded = false;

```
        $(document).on('keydown keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 38) { // Check if up arrow key is pressed or released
                if (e.type === 'keydown' && !animating && !isExpanded) { // If key is pressed and not already expanded
                    animating = true;
                    $(".load").stop().animate({height: "510px"}, 2000, function() {
                        animating = false;
                        isExpanded = true;
                    });
                } else if (e.type === 'keyup' && (isExpanded || animating)) { // If key is released and either expanded or currently animating
                    $(".load").stop().animate({height: "0"}, 2000, function() {
                        animating = false;
                        isExpanded = false;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });`
```

Would help a lot thanks.

Comment: Is the `rotate(180deg)` supposed to be part of your attempt to make the animation from bottom to top? IIRC the jQuery animation only affects the height of the element, so to achieve your effect you have to position the element from its bottom. You must know the final height of your element and it easier with absolute positioning (which is fortunately your case). Try to replace `top: 50px;` by `bottom: 600px;` (600 = 550 + 50) and it should work. You can remove the rotation if it was only meant to achieve the effect

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you don't necessarily need jQuery.
You can achieve the desired by:

- placing your element `position: fixed;` (or `absolute`) at a desired `bottom` coordinate (since you want to animate the height upwards)
- listen (using JavaScript) for the [Event.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values) (or Event.code) for *"ArrowUp"*
- use [Element.classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) to toggle a desired class (`.is-active` in this case)
- don't forget to use [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) when pressing an arrow key to suppress the default behavior of the website scroll
- *animate* using CSS `transition`

```js
const elLoad = document.querySelector("#load");

const handleLoad = (evt) => {
  if (evt.key !== "ArrowUp") return; // Do nothing. Not our key.
  evt.preventDefault(); // prevent default page scroll on arrow key
  elLoad.classList.toggle("is-active", evt.type === "keydown");
};

;["keydown","keyup"].forEach(evType => addEventListener(evType, handleLoad));
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

#load {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0dvh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background: red;
  transition: height 2s;
  
  &.is-active {
    height: 50vh;
  }
}
```

```html
Click this iframe and hold the ArrowUp key
<div id="load"></div>
```

Less code, more performant, and the styling is offloaded completely where it belongs, and that's CSS.